# How to impersonate user token for service to service call

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, adal

My structure of application is Web app calls a WebAPI(lets call it apiA) and that calls another api (lets call it apiB). Now, Web app authenticates the calls via AAD JWT tokens. So, that token would be created for apiA. But I want the api call to apiB to be as the logged in user and dont want to use client secrets etc.

So, in nutshell wants to impersonate the user and get a token for apiB from the token created for apiA or may be if possible have a token which can be good for both apiA and apiB. So, I dont have to get a new token.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try  OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow to delegate the user’s identity and authenticate to the second-tier web API. Please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) :

> > For the scenario when a server application needs to call a web API, it’s helpful to use an example. Imagine that a user has authenticated on a native application, and this native application needs to call a web API. Azure AD issues a JWT access token to call the web API. If the web API needs to call another downstream web API, it can use the on-behalf-of flow to delegate the user’s identity and authenticate to the second-tier web API.

[image]

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) for more details about service to service calls using delegated user identity in the On-Behalf-Of flow .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my questions is specific to how to do it in Node.js as there is no methods available to do this in node.

Comment: See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) you could send the access token request in your web api  , or you could use ADAL for Node.js ,PR [#159](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/pull/159) submitted to add ability to acquire an on-behalf-of token.

Comment: Thanks, for now i have to use the code without impersonation as this pull request is not approved yet. Although, if you know I was trying to use acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword method instead but was getting error that  Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xyz'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Do you know what could be the solution I have already tried updating oauth2AllowImplicitFlow in manifest

Comment: Then you are using the [resource owner flow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) . With this flow ,users do not have any opportunity of providing consent if username & password are passed directly.You need to do [admin consent](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Admin-Consent-for-Permissions-in-Azure-Active-Directory.aspx) with admin account before running your app .